# Gradle - make "assemble" depend on "clean" for all projects

Tags: java, gradle, jar, war

I have several unrelated Java projects built with gradle, some of which are assembled into a `jar` file, others, into a `war`.

I'd like the `assemble` task of all projects to depend on the `clean` task since we've had issues with various old classes getting into assembled jars/wars from the build folder cache. Is there a way of doing that without adding `assemble.dependsOn clean` to each and every `build.gradle`?

Comment: You could add something to your init.gradle, so it applies every time you invoke gradle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can handle this with a global hook in your `./gradle/init.gradle` script.  Anything you put in there is executed on *every* build.

In order to avoid failures on projects that don't have an assemble task you need a filter as well, something like the following will work:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
        if (theTask.name.equals('assemble')) {
            theTask.dependsOn clean
        }
    }
}
```

What this is doing is applying a block to all projects defined (`allproject`).  When each task is added this will run, and when a task with the name `assemble` is added a dependency will be added to `clean`.

Answer (score 0):

From your top level build.gradle

```
submodules {
   assemble.dependsOn clean
}
```

This will apply the `dependsOn` to each subproject

Comment: The OP stated they are /unrelated/ projects